# JS / JQuery - Object doesn't support this property or method - ie7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting the error `Object doesn't support this property or method` linked to the below block of code. It only happens in ie7 and 8.

I'm using JQuery version 1.9.1

Can anyone help?

```
function get_vehicle_data() {
    v = $('#vehicle'+current.vehicle);
    vehicle = {
        id: v.data('vehicle-id'),
        title: v.text(),
        code: v.data('code'),
        example: v.data('example'),
        largeBags: parseInt(v.data('large-bags')),
        smallBags: parseInt(v.data('small-bags')),
        weight: parseInt(v.data('weight')),
        rates: v.data('rates').split(':'),
        passengers: parseInt(v.data('pax'))
    }       
}
```

Comment: Are you also including the [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) plugin? jQuery 1.9 dropped support for IE7 and IE8.

Comment: @Pointy:??? I thought only jQuery 2.0 dropped support for them.

Comment: [No, it was 1.9.](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

Comment: @Pointy: nope: *"jQuery 1.9 runs on Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 (“oldIE”), just like previous versions. Consider it a cleaner, slimmer, modern-API upgrade from jQuery 1.8."* http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/ 1.9 removed a couple of things, but it didn't drop support for older IE.

Comment: However it could still be useful to try older jQuery versions.

Comment: I've tried rolling back to 1.8.1 and 1.7.1 with the migrate plugin. This didn't help I'm afraid. Can't go back further without breaking my code due to use of `.on()` method.

Comment: Oops you guys are right :) I got confused over that page talking about **jQuery** versions 1.7 and 1.8 (because I am dumb)

Comment: Have you checked that `current` exists, and has a property called `vehicle`? This should be pretty easy to debug yourself by simply narrowing the code down bit by bit: first try `v = $('#vehicle'+current.vehicle);` on its own. If that works, add in `vehicle = { id: v.data('vehicle-id') }`; keep going until you find the problem. Once you have the exact line, let us know and we can help.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) -

> Due to the way browsers interact with plugins and external code, the
>   `.data()` method cannot be used on `<object>` (unless it's a Flash
>   plugin), `<applet>` or `<embed>` elements.

You may want to find an alternative

Now that I look at it, it may be how you are defining your `v = $("#vehicle" + current.vehicle);`

Unless you are defining current somewhere else, you are using current as an object which does not have a method "vehicle". This might be your issue.  It would help for you to provide a JSFiddle or the full JS code.

Comment: I'm sure "Object" refers to a JavaScript object, not an HTMLObjectElement.

Comment: I have tried replacing `v.data('foo')` with `v.attr('data-foo')` but that didn't help. Would you say that was the right thing to do?

Comment: @Marc do you have that data set somewhere in your code? Not sure this answers your question, but if you don't set `v.data('vehicle-id')` with something, it will come back undefined. Should look something like `v.data('vehicle-id', '123');`

Comment: @Narukowski the elements that are being read look for example like this: `<span id="vehicle1" class="option" data-vehicle-id="1" data-rates="97.20:46.80:34.80:25.20:23.40:17.55:13.16:9.87" data-code="C1" data-example="KA" data-small-bags="2" data-large-bags="0" data-weight="0" data-pax="4">Economy Car</span>`

Comment: @Marc then why can you get that data using `v.attr("data-vehicle-id");` ?